# Limit records based upon multiple criteria on object and user

Tags: permissions, security, sharing, user, record

I'm looking at limiting access to certain records such that should a record be assigned to a certain group of users (via some field on the object), only those users would be able see or edit those records.

I've tried looking at sharing options but I'm not sure if that is the right path, and is seemingly only available via Classic. is it even possible via lightening? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Take a look at the various Trailhead modules on sharing, including [this one](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/data_security/data_security_records)

Answer (score 0):

In Lightning, Using Account object as an example you have to follow these steps:

1. > Setup > Sharing Settings > Account and Contract > Default Internal Access = Private
2. Go Account Page layout and add "Sharing" button under "Mobile &
   Lightning Actions" as below
3. Now you can do [manual sharing](http://www.infallibletechie.com/2013/08/manual-sharing-in-salesforce.html) allows users to grant one-off access to their individual records for users, roles, and public groups.

[image]